# How to use an keyword instead of $ in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to modify my jQuery to not use `$` because using the `$` symbol would break other JavaScript libraries (eg. Prototype, Scripaculous). How can I use another variable name instead of the `$` symbol?

Comment: Please don't format all your posts in **bold** or *italics*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for compatibility with other libraries, for example:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then use `$j` for jQuery, instead of `$`...or just use `jQuery`, in which case you don't need to set a variable.

*Note:* be sure to include jQuery *after* the other library, so it knows what to give `$` back to.

Comment: Damn, beat me. :grin: kudos and +1

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});
</script>
```